# Count max occurrences using Frequency and ignoring blanks on Spreadsheets

Tags: spreadsheet

Further to this [Thread](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/nested-if-and-and-frequency-array.707943/):

I am trying to write a formula that returns maximum frequency of non blank lines and not "W"s in column B of the array shown [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UFiItdnNTiEjH3Su9jzpSk7iYO2Kv_1JBPV_IWS70_I/edit#gid=0)

This formula returns max consecutive non-W recurrences in the array:

`=ArrayFormula(MAX(FREQUENCY(if(Result<>"w", ID), if(Result<>"w", 0, ID))))`

And I was hoping this formula would return max consecutive non-W (<>="W") and non-blanks (<>=""), but for some reason, it doesn't return the required input:

`=ArrayFormula(MAX(FREQUENCY(if(Result<>"w", if(Result<>"", ID)), if(Result<>"w", if(Result<>"", 0, ID)))))`

I understand that for this example I can search for "L"s, however, I am dealing with much more complicated arrays that have multiple values and blank lines, so solving this issue should help me solve a much bigger dataframe issue I'd like to share with my colleagues on spreadsheets.
PS: If you think the solution is best in Apps Script, I'm happy for any guidance.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: Does Excel have the function ARRAYFORMULA()? Are you using Excel? Because to enter frequency() as an array function you use ctrl+shift+enter.

Comment: I'm using Google Spreadsheets, thanks.

Comment: Then that's probably what is confusing you - the first thread link you give is for Excel...

Comment: What is the best way to get this done on spreadsheets? Continue struggle with formulas or via apps script?